# Prevent user from entering a from date greater than to date c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, date

I am searching data based on two dates a from field and a To field in Asp.net

I want to prevent the user from entering a From date greater than a To date and display a message to the user Please select a valid date range

```
  DateTime InvoiceDateFrom = new DateTime();
DateTime InvoiceDateTo = new DateTime();

if (TxtInvoiceDateFrom.Text.Trim() != "")
{

  //DateTime FromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(TxtInvoiceDateFrom.Text.Trim(), "dd/MM/yyyy", null).AddDays(1);
  InvoiceDateFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(TxtInvoiceDateFrom.Text);
  //DateTime toDate = DateTime.ParseExact(TxtInvoiceDateTo.Text.Trim(), "dd/MM/yyyy", null).AddDays(1);

}

if (TxtInvoiceDateTo.Text.Trim() != "")
{
  InvoiceDateTo = Convert.ToDateTime(TxtInvoiceDateTo.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (InvoiceDateTo < InvoiceDateFrom)
    MessageBox.Show("Please select a valid date range.");
```

Comment: Seems obvious now, but I remember when I was first learning I thought about that and said "there is no way that'll never work. it's too cool!"

Comment: @vini what doesn't work about it? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.op_lessthan%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
 DateTime x = DateTime.Parse("12/8/2012");   //as "12/8/2012" is the your specified date
 dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = x; // or you can use it in one line
```

if you want to prevent the user to choose date greater than today:

```
dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = DateTime.Today;
```

Answer (score -1):

Please see if this is of help!  C# way of doing is fine.  But i would rather suggest javascript.

```
DateTime toDate=DateTime.ParseExact(todateString,"dd/MM/yy",System.Globalization.InvariantCulture);
DateTime fromDate=DateTime.ParseExact(fromdateString,"dd/MM/yy",System.Globalization.InvariantCulture);

int comparison=DateTime.Compare(toDate,fromDate);

if(comparison>=0)
{
     //Post custom error message.
}
```

Comment: We can use comparsion operators. `Compare` method compare `InternalTicks` and return -1, 1, or zero. Comparsion operators work the same way.